# Why is RubyMine asking to install gems that were already installed by bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rubymine

For some reason, RubyMine is constantly complaining about some gems not being installed. However, when I click "Install missing gems" RubyMine is unable to install them:

[image: RubyMine image]

---

Error message:

[image]

Furthermore, the gems seem to be installed already! If `bundler install` command is run, the results indicate these gems are already installed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that probably RubyMine uses different version of ruby that one you have in your PATH. Bundler installs only for your version.

You can check what ruby you are using by simply typing `which ruby` or `ruby -v`.

Also the part about "Don't install bundler as a root." is troubling...